# How can I make my Google Apps Script function work on cell input?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-places-api

I have [a project that I've been working on for a bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69197916/how-can-i-properly-call-a-function-with-a-custom-ui-button-with-a-growing-google/69200323). I've received some excellent help here, and I think I'm almost done and just need one more bit of help to get it working.

The script looks at a Google Sheet and takes a place name entered in Column A and uses the Google Places API to find requested information about it (address, phone number, etc.)

The last bit of help that I need will be able to implement the cell input component. The last user to help me said that

```
function writeToSheet(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = COMBINED2("Food");
  var placeCid = data[4];
  var findText = ss.createTextFinder(placeCid).findAll();
  if(findText.length == 0){
    ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,1,1, data.length).setValues([data])
  }
}
```

would be able use TextFinder to check if the place url exists in the Sheet. If the result of TextFinder is 0, it will call `COMBINED2()` to get the place information and populate the Sheet  with `writeToSheet()`

They noted that

> You can use a cell input in your COMBINED2 by using
> ss.getRange(range).getValue()

Not having a coding background, I have been able to stitch most of this together on my own, but I could use a bit of help in adding that capability to my code. Any help or guidance would be great.

Here is the code in full:

```
// This location basis is used to narrow the search -- e.g. if you were
// building a sheet of bars in NYC, you would want to set it to coordinates
// in NYC.
// You can get this from the url of a Google Maps search.
const LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON = "40.74516247433546, -73.98621366765816"; // e.g. "37.7644856,-122.4472203"

function COMBINED2(text) {
  var API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
  var baseUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json';
  var queryUrl = baseUrl + '?input=' + text + '&inputtype=textquery&key=' + API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var placeId = JSON.parse(json);
  var ID = placeId.candidates[0].place_id;
  var fields = 'name,formatted_address,formatted_phone_number,website,url,types,opening_hours';
  var baseUrl2 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=';
  var queryUrl2 = baseUrl2 + ID + '&fields=' + fields + '&key='+ API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;

  if (ID == '') {
    return 'Give me a Google Places URL...';
  }

  var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl2);
  var json2 = response2.getContentText();
  var place = JSON.parse(json2).result;

  var weekdays = '';
  place.opening_hours.weekday_text.forEach((weekdayText) => {
    weekdays += ( weekdayText + '\r\n' );
  } );

  var data = [
    place.name,
    place.formatted_address,
    place.formatted_phone_number,
    place.website,
    place.url,
    weekdays.trim()
  ];

  return data;
}

function getColumnLastRow(range){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var inputs = ss.getRange(range).getValues();
  return inputs.filter(String).length;
}

function writeToSheet(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = COMBINED2("Food");
  var placeCid = data[4];
  var findText = ss.createTextFinder(placeCid).findAll();
  if(findText.length == 0){
    ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,1,1, data.length).setValues([data])
  }
}

function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();  
  ui.createMenu("Custom Menu")
      .addItem("Get place info","writeToSheet")
      .addToUi();
}
```

---

**Update**

Here is a link to a Shared Sheet in case anyone wants to work on it with me.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KGsk6nkin1CUgpjfHU_AdhF17T_Eh41_g4MLb1CG_Tk/edit#gid=2100307022

Here is what I might not have articulated properly.

I wanted to be able to enter the names of places in Column A

[image]

Then, I want to be able to run the function with the custom menu feature. If TextFinder does not find the Place URL for the given place, it will look up the data and write it to the Sheet.

I wanted to limit the number of API calls with this and to make sure the data was written to the Sheet so that it does not need to be pulled each time the Sheet is reopened.

---

**Finished Product**

Big thanks to Lamblichus for sticking this out with me. I hope this helps other people some day.

Here is the finished code:

```
// This location basis is used to narrow the search -- e.g. if you were
// building a sheet of bars in NYC, you would want to set it to coordinates
// in NYC.
// You can get this from the url of a Google Maps search.
const LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON = "ENTER_GPS_COORDINATES_HERE"; // e.g. "37.7644856,-122.4472203"

function COMBINED2(text) {
  var API_KEY = 'ENTER_API_KEY_HERE';
  var baseUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json';
  var queryUrl = baseUrl + '?input=' + text + '&inputtype=textquery&key=' + API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var placeId = JSON.parse(json);
  var ID = placeId.candidates[0].place_id;
  var fields = 'name,formatted_address,formatted_phone_number,website,url,types,opening_hours';
  var baseUrl2 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=';
  var queryUrl2 = baseUrl2 + ID + '&fields=' + fields + '&key='+ API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;

  if (ID == '') {
    return 'Give me a Google Places URL...';
  }

  var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl2);
  var json2 = response2.getContentText();
  var place = JSON.parse(json2).result;

  var weekdays = '';
  if (place.opening_hours && place.opening_hours.weekday_text) {
    place.opening_hours.weekday_text.forEach((weekdayText) => {
      weekdays += ( weekdayText + '\r\n' );
    } );
  }

  var data = [
    place.name,
    place.formatted_address,
    place.formatted_phone_number,
    place.website,
    place.url,
    weekdays.trim()
  ];

  return data;
}

function writeToSheet() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const FIRST_ROW = 2;
  const sourceData = sheet.getRange(FIRST_ROW, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-FIRST_ROW+1, 6)
                          .getValues().filter(row => String(row[0]));
  for (let i = 0; i < sourceData.length; i++) {
    const sourceRow = sourceData[i];
    if (sourceRow[4] === "") {
      const text = sourceRow[0];
      const data = COMBINED2(text);
      sheet.getRange(FIRST_ROW+i, 2, 1, data.length).setValues([data]);
    }
  }
}

function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();  
  ui.createMenu("Custom Menu")
      .addItem("Get place info","writeToSheet")
      .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: So you want the parameter `text` in `COMBINED2(text)` to refer to a value from a certain cell? Do you know which cell from which sheet would that be? Maybe it would be the currently selected cell?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to be able to enter the name of a place in Column A and have the `COMBINED2` function reference that and populate the cells next to it in that same row with the requested information.

Comment: Ok, column A, but how would the row be defined? Would it be the selected cell? It's not clear, based on the information you provided.

Comment: Sorry for being inarticulate. See above screenshot and link to a Shared Sheet. 
I wanted to be able to enter in names of places in Google Sheets in Column A. Then it uses Custom Menu function to call the `COMBINED2` function to look at each entry and, if TextFinder checks and sees that it has no entry in the Place URL, it will run the function to pull that place's data and write it to the sheet. The key is that it only runs the function if it sees there is no Place URL as to limit my API calls and that it writes the info to the Sheet so it doesn't look it up every time the Sheet is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Desired goal:

If I understand you correctly, for each value in column `A`, you want to retrieve some related data from Maps API and paste it to columns `B-F`, **if column E is not currently populated**.

#### Issues:

- You are only providing the last value from column `A` to `COMBINED2`, but you want to loop through all values in column `A` and fetch the desired information for all of them (as long as the `Place URL` -column E- is not already populated).
- If you want to avoid calling Maps API if the `Place URL` is not populated, using [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) **after** calling Maps API doesn't make sense; you don't limit your calls to the API if you do that. If you just want to check whether the `Place URL` column is populated, I'd suggest checking whether the cell is empty or not, and calling Maps API if it's empty.

#### Proposed workflow:

- Retrieve all values from the sheet, including not just column `A` but also `E` (for practical purposes, all 6 columns are fetched in the sample below, since it can be done in one call), using [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).
- Iterate through the rows (for example, using [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)), and for each row, check that the cell in `E` is populated.
- If the cell in `E` (`Place URL`) is empty, use the value in `A` as the parameter for `COMBINED2` and write the resulting `data` to columns `B-F`, as you are currently doing.

#### Code sample:

```
function writeToSheet() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const FIRST_ROW = 2;
  const sourceData = sheet.getRange(FIRST_ROW, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-FIRST_ROW+1, 6)
                          .getValues().filter(row => String(row[0]));
  for (let i = 0; i < sourceData.length; i++) {
    const sourceRow = sourceData[i];
    if (sourceRow[4] === "") {
      const text = sourceRow[0];
      const data = COMBINED2(text);
      sheet.getRange(FIRST_ROW+i, 2, 1, data.length).setValues([data]);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Update:

For names in which Places API doesn't return `opening_hours`, consider checking if this exists first:

```
function COMBINED2(text) {

  // ... REST OF YOUR FUNCTION ...

  var weekdays = '';
  if (place.opening_hours && place.opening_hours.weekday_text) {
    place.opening_hours.weekday_text.forEach((weekdayText) => {
      weekdays += ( weekdayText + '\r\n' );
    } );
  }

  var data = [
    place.name,
    place.formatted_address,
    place.formatted_phone_number,
    place.website,
    place.url,
    weekdays.trim()
  ];

  return data;
}
```

Comment: I attempted to use this after overwriting what I had for `writeToSheet()` and eliminating the `getColumnLastRow(range)` but it only worked on the first entry. The Sheet threw an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'weekday_text' of undefined` after that. Looks like it's very close though!

Comment: Actually, I stand corrected. It works up to a point. I got that error when trying to run it on the 3 places in the example screenshot/shared Sheet in the OP. I attempted to use it on another set of places in a Sheet I'm building for a vacation. The first row was my AirBnB, so it wasn't going to find anything for that, and it skipped it no problem. It was able to find the information for rows 3-8, but then it stopped with that same error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'weekday_text' of undefined` and did nothing for rows 9-54. Is this a Google Places API error or something to do with the JS?

Comment: @JeffAbrahams This has to do with Places API, since the values from column `A` are getting correctly returned and passed as parameters to `COMBINED2` (which was your main issue). For certain values from column `A`, `opening_hours` is not available. As a workaround, I'd suggest checking whether `opening_hours` exist before trying to get information from it, and leave the cell blank if it doesn't exist. See the section `Updated` at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I think you are right that it is a Places API issue. I'm using an old version of the `COMBINED2()` which also pulls the place.name (which would be redundant if it is already in Column A), and I can see that it is mismatching some places, and that's why it is likely throwing this error. Your change did make it farther, this time covering rows 9-28 out of 54. This time it threw `TypeError: Cannot read property 'place_id' of undefined` which I guess stems from the same Places API issue. Is there a way to write something that skips a place that throws an error instead of stopping everything?

Comment: I'm an idiot... You nailed it from the start. The reason I was getting all of these errors was because I neglected to replace the `LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON` GPS coordinates with the proper city. I was using NYC coordinates when making searches for San Diego places. I just ran it against my Sheet of 50+ San Diego places, and they all came back perfectly. Thank you so much for your help with this. I hope it helps you and others some day. If you ever make it to NYC, I owe you a beer and a slice of pizza.

Comment: @JeffAbrahams Sure, just before the failing line `var ID = placeId.candidates[0].place_id;` add `if (!placeId.candidates[0]) return new Array(6);`. This way the function ends and returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

By using the event trigger function...

```
function onEdit(e){
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(insert your range in A1 format).setValue("anything you want to add into the cell")
}

function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = COMBINED2("Food");
  var placeCid = data[4];
  var findText = ss.createTextFinder(placeCid).findAll();
  if(findText.length == 0){
    ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,1,1, data.length).setValues([data])
  }
}
```

u need to specifically tell google apps script that the function is as such so that your function will execute when a event object known as e has happened.
You can read more about it on [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers?hl=en)

Comment: I was hoping to run this as a custom menu function. Using a trigger might work, but when I grow this out a bit, I was hoping to keep it to using a few different functions from the Sheet. In the next iteration, I wanted to have a separate function that would check over data already in the Sheet for updates and highlight a cell if something changed so I knew to update my Google MyMap.